# Data Validation - List - with the source of the list is in the raw data (has multiple copy of value)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to make a data validation in a list format in excel spreadsheet
But I don't want to make a new sheet or any new table to put the list source first...
I want to take a list source from one column in the existing raw data placed in some sheet...
But the problem is, that column has multiple copy of value
I just want to list one of each value that the column has...
So if the raw data updated with new variable at that column the list will automatically updated
And also I don't want to format my raw data into a table format (some tutorial tell to format the data as table so it can be named and every column can be called with its header)
Is there any way to do that??

Comment: not sure if you can accomplish this (without vba) without using an additional column. have a look at [this](http://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/03/30/how-to-extract-a-unique-list-and-the-duplicates-in-excel-from-one-column/) for some ideas.

Comment: and [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-excel/data-validation-named-range-returning-array/bdb44056-700b-413e-9333-bf1942ac2f2c) is the reason it won't work against the column as is